# Wordpress plugin for ad management

Tags: wordpress

Has any one come across a Wordpress plugin for banner ad management? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two. I used banner garden.

1. [Banner Garden](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/banner-garden/)
2. [AdServe](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adserve/)

Banner Garden will do what you want:

- Flash, image and ad code banners
- Rotate banners randomly
- WordPress Media Library for uploading or selecting flash/image
- set the start and/or the end time of a campaign

Answer (score 0):

The [Sponsor Ad Management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cd-ad-sponsor/) plugin will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Advertising Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advertising-manager/)

Features:

- The most popular ad plugin for
  WordPress, with new features coming
  every single month
- Simple way to import all of your ads
- Widget can be used to place ads in
  the sidebar
- Put ads in your blog posts with the
  click of a button
- Ads can be placed in your templates
  with a single PHP function
- Ad limitations by author, category,
  tag, page type, and much more
- Auto-recognition for 15 of the most
  popular ad networks, so you can
  manage these ads in your WordPress
  blog rather than going to each
  website.

Comment: Advertising Manager is REALLY buggy though... I don't advise using it for any serious blog. It seemed really perfect... Until I had issues with it... Then realized, many issues are just a result of lazy programming. No telling what sort of security problems lie within it, either.